# Convert 4K .mp4 to 4K .flv possible?

Tags: flv, 4k-resolution

Whats the best way to convert a 4K h.264 encoded mp4 video to a 4k resolution .flv?

Is it even possible?

Are there size constraints on the .flv format?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but if your internet connection is fast enough, just upload to youtube and download the file again. It should be returned in FLV-format, since that's what youtube uses.

Answer (score -1):

I personally suppose that all sorts of conversions are possible, as long as your source file is not corrupted and you have a well configured file converter like [DVDVideoSoft Free Studio](http://download.dvdvideosoft.com) . You could also try [online-convert](http://www.online-convert.com/).

Comment: DVDVideoSoft violates the FFmpeg license (and many others). Frequently spammed by shills on forums, mailing lists, Reddit, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I always use **Wondershare Video Converter** Software to convert  a file from one format to another format. This makes the conversion very easy and the output file has near about no quality loss unless you change it to lower size. Just add the file and select the required format you want. and Convert it.

[image]

You can download the trial version from the link given [from it's official website](http://www.wondershare.com/pro/video-converter-ultimate.html)

Comment: Terrible software. Violates the FFmpeg license (and many others). Frequently spammed by shills on forums, mailing lists, Reddit, etc.

Comment: @llogan, this may be true (I have no clue), in which case downvotes & comments are appropriate (claims of license violations would benefit from a citation).  This particular post isn't spam; posters are entitled to their opinion based on their own experience.  Other products also get legit recommendations by members, but the companies choose to spam us.  The company's actions on other posts don't invalidate legit posts.  This post has attracted a deletion vote, but that should not be used for the issues raised for this post, or we would end up deleting everything we disagree with.

Comment: @fixer1234 I didn't call this particular post spam or the poster a spammer. I am just pointing out the awful practices of the software authors.